# SvelteKit (this) in each loop

Tags: each, sveltekit

How do can you target current element in an each loop in SvelteKit, eg this:

```
{#each data as item,i}
<img on:load={()=>{ this.classList.add("x"); }}
```

Comment: Can you expand your question a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating arrow function without any arguments you can use `event` as first argument and then access the element as `event.target`

```
{#each data as item,i}
    <img on:load={(event)=>{ event.target.classList.add("x"); }} ... />
{/each}
```